# select unique trunc(sysdate-370 + level, 'IW') AS datetime from dual connect by level <= 360 order by datetime

Tags: oracle, datetime

Can someone explain me what does the below oracle query do and what is it's output?

```
select unique trunc(sysdate-370 + level, 'IW') AS datetime from dual 
connect by level <= 360 order by datetime;
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a good title for your question?

Comment: The query you posted appears to generate, in a very clumsy and slightly incorrect and inefficient way (unimportant though, since the amount of processing is small anyway), the dates of every Monday for approximately the past year (rolling window: one year **ending today**), except for the Mondays of the current and the immediately preceding week. It would be really good if there were comments or documentation to confirm that this was indeed the *intent* of the code; then it could be rewritten in a much better way.

Answer (score 2):

```
select sysdate-370 + level AS datetime
from   dual 
connect by level <= 360;
```

Will generate 360 rows starting with the current date/time minus 370 days plus one day per row. So rows between 369 and 10 days before the current date/time.

[`TRUNC( datetime, 'IW' )`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions271.htm#SQLRF52058) will truncate the date to the start of the ISO week (midnight on Monday of that week - irrespective of the NLS settings for date language and/or territory that affect some other options for truncating dates). So you will end up with duplicate rows for each generated row that is in the same week.

The `UNIQUE` keyword will get rid of those duplicate rows.

The `order by datetime` will order the results in ascending date order - however, the rows are generated in ascending order so this clause is unnecessary.

So the output will be 52 or 53 rows (depending on what the current day of the week is) starting with Monday midnight of each week containing the date 369 days before the current day up until the week containing 10 days before the current date.

Answer (score 0):

The output (when run on 13th September 2017) is 52 rows (I skipped a few):

```
05-SEP-2016
12-SEP-2016
19-SEP-2016
26-SEP-2016
03-OCT-2016
...
31-JUL-2017
07-AUG-2017
14-AUG-2017
21-AUG-2017
28-AUG-2017
```

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions271.htm#SQLRF52058) `trunc(dateval, 'IW')` truncates to:

> Same day of the week as the first day of the calendar week as defined by the ISO 8601 standard, which is Monday

`connect by level <= N` is a trick for producing a set of N rows with `level` values from 1 to N.

Comment: Do you exactly know what does trunc(somedate 'IW') do? I am still not clear on this IW option.

Comment: This does not always generate 52 rows.